# multiple variables initialization in a single line doesn't work

Tags: c++

thanks for entering this post, I've been coding in c++ recently and came across an issue while trying to initialize 5 member variables of a class Input in a single line.
This member variables were defined in the header file and in the source file I set their values to false within the constructor.
when i try to initialize them separately, each one to false, the application works as expected, however when I try to intiialize all of the 5 boolean variables to false, it's working as if I haven't set any of them to false.
I tried to output the value of a variable m_isWindowCloseButtonClicked and it outputs 205, no idea why, however, when I inidivudallly initialize each one of these booleans it output that variable value as 0, as expected

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not paste images - copy the code itself.

Comment: `m_isKeyPressed, m_isWindowCloseButtonClicked, m_isRightMouseButtonClicked, m_isLeftMouseButtonClicked, m_isMiddleMouseButtonClicked = false;` does not set all five of those variables to `false`. Where did you get the idea that it would?

Answer (score 1):

Do not paste images instead of code, copy the code.

Also, when initializing multiple variables, don't use `,` to specify the variables. This won't work as expected:

```
a, b, c = false;
```

Use instead:

```
a = b = c = false;
```

Comment: thanks, don't know why I thought this would work :\